# Laravel not setting session, set_cookie is missing from response header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cookies, laravel-session

After form submission, it shows "419|page expired." I used `@csrf` in the form and its working on my local server. However, I am facing the issue on the live server. Any help? I have three types of users and implemented multi auth for them. The form doesn't even post to the Controller.

**config/auth.php**

```php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'vendor',
        'passwords' => 'vendors',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'manager' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'managers',
        ],
        'vendor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'managers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Manager::class,
        ],
        'vendors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Vendor::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'managers' => [
            'provider' => 'managers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'vendors' => [
            'provider' => 'vendors',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**RedirectedIfAuthenticated.php**

```php
<?php

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        case 'manager':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('manager.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        case 'vendor':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('vendor.dashboard');
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/home');
            }
            break;
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: What is your session driver set to? https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#configuration

Comment: Show the code to your HTML form.